# Запретить зум и оверскроллинг в мобильном Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, reactjs

Идея в том, чтобы сайт смотрелся как приложение. Под Android достаточно было:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

С Safari под iOS это не работает.

1. Пользователи могут зумить.
2. При проскролливании списка до самого низу наблюдается оверскролл.

Как отключить зум и оверскролинг в Safari под iOS в браузере и WebView? Если посоветуете какой-то готовый плагин для этого под React, будет ещё лучше.

Comment: (крайне странно, что Safari этого не умеет, ибо meta viewport впервые появился именно в Safari именно под iOS)

Comment: @andreymal в 10 iOS они это поменяли.

Comment: А вы не интересовались почему Эппл запретил такое? Если вы делаете не игру в браузере, то вы не должны хотеть запрещать пользователям зум — это антипаттерн разработки. Есть множество людей (я в их числе), которые активно пользуются зумом на мобиле, потому что имеют не очень хорошее зрение. И, например, мобильная версия Фейсбука, в котором запрещено зумить, вызывает не радость, что всё всегда красиво, а только раздражение.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko я в курсе для чего это было сделано. И да, это частично игра)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй что-то в этом роде:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
  event = event.originalEvent || event;
  if(event.scale !== 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } 
}, false);
```

Погуглил много решений и узнал, что через атрибуты viewport это не решается именно в Safari.